# Another page poping up instead of keyboard

Tags: java, android

I want to open calculator which I created. This is the code I wrote:

```
  TextView.OnClickListener listener = new TextView.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
        InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(textOut1.getWindowToken(), 0);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(textOut2.getWindowToken(), 0);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(textOut3.getWindowToken(), 0);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(textOut5.getWindowToken(), 0);

               startActivity (new Intent("com.easyPhys.start.calculator")); 

        }
    };
    textOut1.setOnClickListener(listener);
    textOut2.setOnClickListener(listener);
    textOut3.setOnClickListener(listener);
    textOut5.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

But what happens is virtual keyboard opens and my calculator opens only than I press ENTER. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Could you please rephrase? For what I understood, you created a calculator for Android, but it doesn't open right away?

Comment: Virtual keyboard opens as usualy but only then I press ENTER key (in virtual keyboard) my calculator pops out. I hope you understand my problem now

Comment: Isn't the calculator activity your main application activity? It should appear right away without the need to start an activity like you do in the snippet above.

Comment: even changing     if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL){
               startActivity (new Intent("com.easyPhys.start.calculator")); 
           }
with only     startActivity (new Intent("com.easyPhys.start.calculator"));    gives the same

Comment: You souldn't need to start a specific activity to show your calculator activity. You are also trying to do that inside an Action Listener, which doesn't seem like what you want to achieve. Could you please provide the entire classes where you've created/modified code?

Comment: I want that calculator would open when I press TextView area. Code won't fit in comment area and I don't think it would give something useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the onClick event listener on the TextView, instead of the OnEditorActionListener.
For it to work you also need to add the following attribute to the TextView in the xml.

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Don't forget it, without it it won't work.

The OnEditorActionListener only fires when some action is performed on the editor, and that's why the activity only shows when you click the keyboard. On the other hand, the onClick listener should fire right after you click the TextView.

Comment: There is one small problem. When I come back to the main page by pressing return button I press another textView and keyboard appears again. This is very confusing

Comment: Is it possible to dissable it in html file?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the onClick listener with all the other TextViews?

Comment: Have you added the android:clickable="true" attribute to all the TextViews?